# Use key storage for all ansible related commands

Tags: ansible, rundeck

Can I make the Ansible Resource Model Source use the key storage for the ansible ssh key?

In fact, what I need is for rundeck to always use private key in key storage for all ssh communications, regardless of how it is initiated.

Otherwise the key storage doesn't help much, because I'll still need to create a docker secret or something to supply the ssh key.

Answer (score 0):

That was requested [here](https://github.com/Batix/rundeck-ansible-plugin/issues/298). Maybe we'll see it in the next [plugin](https://github.com/Batix/rundeck-ansible-plugin) releases.